# Angular Directives - Utilizing ng-transclude

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following simple index.html:

```
<header>
    <h1> Acme Inc. </h1>
</header>

<section>
    <opt-in>
        <!-- set brand logo image as background for this css class  -->
        <div class="brand-logo"></div>
    </opt-in>
</section>
```

I am linking this to an app.js file that has:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('optIn', function () {
return {
    templateUrl: 'opt-in-template.html',
    restrict: 'AE',
    transclude: true,
}
});
```

and the opt-in-template.html looks like:

```
<div class="opt-in-form">
<form>
    <input placeholder="first name" />
    <input placeholder="last name" />
    <input placeholder="email" />
    <button type="submit"> Give us yr infoz!</button>
</form>
```

My goal is to utilize transclude so that the form and the "div class=brand-logo" show up in the same div in the index.html.

Currently, my index.html shows the brand-logo class, but doesn't actually render the form in the view. Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close your div tag `<div class="opt-in-form">` in the template:
2. Use `ng-transclude`in your directive template where you want to put your `<div class="brand-logo"></div>`.

   Give us yr infoz!

Make an [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lq1bdZ26iLsVwLdJ7HdZ?p=preview). Hope it works. Any problems let me know plz.

Comment: Yin, perfect explanation. Thank you!